# How to change the order of Jquery in the footer of my theme?

Tags: functions, jquery

At the top of my functions.php is this code:

```
function load_theme_scripts() {
// Load stylesheets.
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.5');

// Load our main stylesheet.
wp_enqueue_style('infosec conferences', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '1.0');

//Load scripts
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js', array(), '2.1.1', false); // was set to false
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '20160101', true);
}

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_theme_scripts');
```

So - if you look at the code jquery is loaded in the theme and, if I change the variable to 'true' then the script is loaded to the footer. The problem is that if I do set it to ''true' WordPress places the jquery script to the absolute bottom of the folder (i.e. the last script to be loaded).

I need it to be above the rest of my Javascript...

The other Javascript is loaded like this:

```
 function Javascript123() {
   if ( is_page_template( array('template-name.php'))){
 ?>
   <script type="text/javascript"> XXX </script>
 <?php
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'Javascript123' );
```

My question is - how do I make either the above Script be at the absolute bottom (next to < /body> or how do I make the Jquery order to my preference? Thanks for all direction.

Comment: WordPress bundles jQuery, why are you trying to load your own, and in a different place? Your just begging for conflicts with other plugins if you do tis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Understand wp_enqueue's dependencies parameter**

You need to ensure the other script depends on jQuery being ready before it loads. Checking the wp_enqueue usage example:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>
```

It is `$deps` (dependencies) that we can utilise for this purpose.

**Properly *enqueue* the second script, and leverage that parameter**

Secondly you should use the enqueue function to conditionally load the second script:

```
if ( is_page_template( array('template-name.php'))){
 wp_register_script('xxx', '/path/to/script/xxx.js', array('jquery'),'1.0',true);
 wp_enqueue_script('xxx');
}
```

Notice the `array('jquery')` which stops this script loading before jQuery is ready.